# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, internal

I keep getting this error on a new server i have recently starting using.

At home on my home server it works fine, at my workplace my site also works fine on their server but on this server everytime i try to go from one .php document to another .php document and run the code it comes up with this error.

Please help i cannot understand it, i have tried all sorts, ive used different code, no code, checked if jumping to a html doc works and its does it just doesnt seem to like what I'm doing and ive never seen anything like this before.

This is the link to go to the php document to destroy the session:

```
<div class="logoutDiv">Or <a href="lib/html/destroy.php">Goooodbyyyee!</a></div>
```

This is the code inside that php document:

```
<?php session_start(); session_destroy(); header('Location: ../../index.php'); ?>
```

Here's the error page: unihub.itsyoureasel.com/lib/html/destroy.php

Comment: Look in the server logs or provide a link and/or code here.

Comment: That's strange. You have to take a look at the logs. If you don't have access to them, try enabling error reporting with ini_set('display_errors', 1) and error_reporting(E_ALL) in the first lines of your script.

Comment: The error log i have doesn't reckon this error ever happened, it has my errors from earlier (which were PHP coding errors and came up on the page as the PHP config is set to show errors already) Its just driving me crazy now, really driving me up the wall! Thank you for your help though, i really appreciate it!

Comment: are you using Apache or ISS? I would guess this to be a possible .htaccess error, or an error in ISS configuration

Comment: Im using Apache, I've just figured out the error though. Its something to do with creating php files using Aptana on top of eclipse. My Original files i created without Aptana and uploaded work, i just copied my original file (index.php) to another location renamed it and changed to code to what i desired and hey presto it works now :/ .... :D :D thank you all for your help guys :D

Comment: @Ash, please post an answer to your question detailing your solution so that this question **might** prove useful to someone else at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Apache. I've just figured out the error.

It's an odd one but seems to be something to do with creating .php files using Aptana. My original files I created without Aptana and uploaded, work. I just copied my original file (index.php) to another location renamed it and changed to code to what i desired and hey presto it works now.

Strange but I'm guessing it is something to do with the way Aptana creates the meta data etc. to the file as you actually type the extension you wish for it to be where as in plain eclipse for php dev's you choose a php file type from a list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in your .htaccess file or in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file .
Check what errors logs say in /var/log/httpd folder .

Comment: Agree, usually this kind of errors belongs to the web server (apache?)

Comment: Yeah it is Apache, I found the error was with the certain .php files I was creating, i dont have access to the htaccess files but i can see them :/ thank you for the help guys i have a feeling it may also be to do with that.